# How to call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macros, variadic-functions

I created a variadic method by Objective-C:

```
+ (void)myFunc:(NSString *)message, ... ;
```

and I call to this variadic method by macro:

```
#define TESTLOG(x,...) [MyExample myFunc:(x), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

till where it is ok, but what about swift?

Now I try to call myFunc from swift code, unfortunately swift don't recognized the ... syntax,
so how I can call Objective-C variadic method from Swift code without give up on the macro?

The goal is to call variadic method from swift code and Objective-c code by macro

Comment: changing the macro for swift to go with its syntax is not the right way to do it ?
Myexample.myFunc(x,..)